How to deny all actions except one in an IAM resource policy
There is an IAM policy for a role granting access to a bucket. I would like the DENY part of the bucket policy to override that access. I am trying to craft an S3 bucket policy to deny all actions except one (S3:GetBucketLocation) in the IAM resource policy, with a condition on the principal ARN. I can't seem to get it to work (either GetBucketLocation is denied or other actions are allowed). Is there a standard pattern for this?
I am hoping for something like:
DENY s3:* except GetBucketLocation
ALLOW s3:GetBucketLocation
Is there a way to do this? Part of the struggle is understanding how different policy statements interact and how identity and resource policies interact. I read the AWS docs but it's still quite unclear to me. Thanks!!

What does "can't seem to get it to work" mean?  Do you mean there are actual errors when you try to apply the policy?  Or do you mean the policy does not have the desired effect (it allows more actions, or fewer, than you intended)?

Amazon S3 buckets are private by default. It is generally best to avoid using Deny policies since they override Allow policies. So, start with the fact that nobody has any permission on the bucket unless an IAM Policy or a Bucket Policy grants them access. Then, grant them the S3:GetBucketLocation permission. This will meet your objective without needing a Deny policy (unless you have other policies that are granting them access, in which case please add this detail to your question).

This statement does not give permissions, it denies all except this.  You will have to provide another statement in IAM and/or S3 policy to give permssions.
{
"Effect": "Deny",
"NotAction": ["service:Action"],
"Resource": "*",
"Principal": "arn:..."
}

You may also want to look at Permissions Boundaries.
